# In Corda, timeout when creating an RPC proxy in webapp

Tags: corda

I'm getting this error when trying to create an RPC proxy in my Spring web app:

```
ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[
    errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119013: 
    Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
]
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeController' defined in file [D:\Development\acme\acme-tech\acme-tech-spring\out\production\classes\com\acme\tech\spring\controllers\NodeController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.acme.tech.spring.controllers.NodeController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.acme.tech.spring.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.acme.tech.spring.controllers.NodeController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:191) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:na]
    at com.acme.tech.shared.services.rpc.RPCProxyProvider.getRPCProxy(RPCProxyProvider.kt:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.acme.tech.spring.controllers.Controller.<init>(Controller.kt:7) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.acme.tech.spring.controllers.NodeController.<init>(NodeController.kt:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by attempting to connect to the node's RPC broker before the broker is ready.

Comment: Hi Joel. My node is up with RPC. I am even able to telnet into it. But I am still getting the above error. Please help.

Comment: Hi Joel, please ignore the above. I was sending a wrong password!!